# How do I retrieve association data along with relational data in TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, relational-database, typeorm

I have this entity class. It's an association between two tables.

```js
import { Column, Entity, Index, JoinColumn, ManyToOne } from "typeorm";
import { Classroom } from "./Classroom";
import { Teacher } from "./Teacher";

@Index("fk_class_has_teacher_teacher1_idx", ["teacherId"], {})
@Index("fk_class_has_teacher_class1_idx", ["classId"], {})
@Entity("teacherclassroom", { schema: "school" })
export class Teacherclassroom {
  @Column("int", { primary: true, name: "class_id" })
  classId: number;

  @Column("int", { primary: true, name: "teacher_id" })
  teacherId: number;

  @Column("datetime", {
    name: "reg_date",
    nullable: true,
    default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
  })
  regDate: Date | null;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Classroom,
    classroom => classroom.teacherclassrooms,
    { onDelete: "NO ACTION", onUpdate: "NO ACTION" }
  )
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "class_id", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
  class: Classroom;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Teacher,
    teacher => teacher.teacherclassrooms,
    { onDelete: "NO ACTION", onUpdate: "NO ACTION" }
  )
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "teacher_id", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
  teacher: Teacher;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get Teacher and Classroom details when I'm retrieving a row from this association. I did it as follows,

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection, getRepository } from "typeorm";
import { Teacherclassroom } from "./entity/Teacherclassroom";
import { Classroom } from "./entity/Classroom";
import { Teacher } from "./entity/Teacher";

createConnection().then(async connection => {

    const myRepository = getRepository(Teacherclassroom);
    const test = myRepository.find({ relations: ["teacher", "classroom"] });
    console.log(test);

}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I'm getting this error,

```
Relation was not found, please check if it is correct and really exist in your entity.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Change `class` to `classroom` in Classroom relation

```
@ManyToOne(() => Classroom,classroom => classroom.teacherclassrooms,
{ onDelete: "NO ACTION", onUpdate: "NO ACTION" })
@JoinColumn([{ name: "class_id", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
classroom: Classroom;
```

Comment: That fixed it. typeorm-model-generator package seems to have a problem with handling table names containing js keywords.